# GEE for multilevel data

Tags: statistical-significance, generalized-estimating-equations

Can GEE handle a 2-level and 3-level hierarchical clustering, i.e. repeated measures per individual nested in cities, and cities nested in provinces? If yes, how can should I write the GEE for these stages? What should be the working correlation?

Comment: An interesting aspect of the GEE is that, since it effectively marginalizes over correlation structures, you can ignore them completely and apply an independent working covariance structure to obtain correct standard error estimates. This is usually exploited when correlation structures are unknown, like relatedness is small community studies. However, working independence structures are also used many times when correlation structures are known.

Comment: thanks please tell me how i can construct correlation matrix for 3 level?

Comment: can i construct correlation matrix for level 1 and then to level 2 and then to level 3 and sum these correlation structures?